# .NET Help using TCP classes

Tags: c#, tcp, network-programming, bytebuffer, data-representation

I'm trying to learn network programming and I'm trying to create a TCP server and TCP client.

The server will start and listen for connections. The client will connect and send a string to the server.
Then server will reply with a string containing the received string.

The issue I'm facing is that for the first try this works but after that sometimes the client receive an empty reply.

Below is the code for the server:

```
public void handlerThread()
{
 TcpClient TcpClient = clients[clients.Count - 1]; 
 NetworkStream networkStream = TcpClient.GetStream();
 int i = -1;
 while (TcpClient.Connected )
 {
  Byte[] data = new Byte[1024];
  if ((i=networkStream.Read(data, 0, data.Length)) != 0)
  {
   string incomingMessage = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
   Debug.WriteLine("DDB Server incomingMessage: " + incomingMessage);
   this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => lbMessage.Items.Add("Message received is: " + incomingMessage)));
   // Send back a response.
   data = new Byte[1024];
   string outMessage = string.Empty;
   outMessage = "Recieved msg: " + incomingMessage;
   data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(outMessage);
   networkStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
   Debug.WriteLine("DDB Server Reply: " + outMessage);
   this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => lblStatus.Text = "Sent reply!"));
  }
 }
}
```

The client's code:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_txtBoxMsg.Text))
 {
  try
  {
   Byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_txtBoxMsg.Text);
   stream = client.GetStream();
   // Send the message to the connected TcpServer. 
   stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
   Debug.WriteLine("DDB Client Message: " + _txtBoxMsg.Text);
   data = new Byte[1024];
   String responseData = String.Empty;
   Int32 bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
   responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);
   Debug.WriteLine("DDB Client recieved: " + responseData);
   lbMsgs.Items.Add(string.Format("Received: {0}", responseData));
  }
  catch (ArgumentNullException ex)
  {
   MessageBox.Show("ArgumentNullException: " + ex); ;
  }
  catch (SocketException ex)
  {
   MessageBox.Show("SocketException: " + ex);
  }
 }
 else
  MessageBox.Show("You did not enter a message to be sent to server!", "Please enter a message", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
}
```

I noticed something while using Debug.WriteLine() the first run the message is displayed correctly. after that the messages are next to each other (as if I was using Debug.Write()).
[image: Behavior]
Could it be that the byte representation for the messages is being corrupted (for example the return character or something)?

Comment: TCP works in terms of streams of bytes. Not messages. If you want messages, it's up to you to implement them on top of that stream of bytes (or switch to a technology that already implements messages atop TCP). Importantly, calls to `Read` on one end are *not* guaranteed to match 1-1 with calls to `Write` at the other end. You need to always pay attention to the return value from `Read` (currently, on your server side you ignore it and convert your entire `data` buffer to a string even if it only contained one valid byte). And you need to deal with partial messages or multiple messages.

Comment: @Damien Thanks for your feedback. If you mean by messages the strings it just to illustrate the TCP activity. Shouldn't the call if its only 1-client 1-server be 1-1?
You are correct I should check the output from Read to see how many bytes are read.
Can you also suggest a good reading material for network programming?

Comment: If you call `Write` twice at one end, there's no guarantee of how many times you'll have to call `Read` at the other end. You'll eventually receive all of the bytes that were included in both calls to `Write`, but there's no guarantee that you'll get to call `Read` exactly twice and that the first `Read` reproduces a buffer of exactly the same size as the first `Write`. It's *just* a stream of bytes, so far as TCP is concerned. If you want to be able to call "Send" at one side and call "Receive" at the other, and each call is matched 1-1, what you're looking for is *messages*.

Comment: Thanks. I'm starting to understand. Is the cause for this that TCP might have to resend packets, so that will cause Read to be called multiple times?